# Can't install EGit in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, egit

I'm trying to get the EGit plugin and I'm about to pull my hair out. Okay, this is what's happening -- I go to the Install New Software page and I've added the EGit repo, but the window below doesn't show anything; it just says "pending". After a while I get an error saying it timed out.

I've tried unchecking everything one at a time on the "Available Software Sites" page but that doesn't work.

I've tried unchecking the "contact all update sites during install.." box but that doesn't work.

I've tried downloading it on the marketplace but when I try and open it I get the same issue, it just times out.

The internal web browser is working. I'm not working behind a proxy. I need some help. PLEASE!

Answer (score 0):

In the Indigo Release there is the "Eclipse EGit",  "Eclipse Mylyn to GitHub connector"  and "JGit" in Indigo R2 release site. Do you get to that point or are you trying to load a site other than Indigo Release? The next step is to Calculate Requirements and Dependencies. If you downloaded something it is probably the GitHub plugin/Feature distrib. You should be able to copy those packages into the respective folder and restart Eclipse.

Your best bet is to install from the Eclipse release site and then go to Menu -> Window -> Open Perspective -> Other and you should see a GitHub Repository Explorer perspective.

Otherwise show us what site your trying to load from or explain the problem better.